# ggplot2 | Showing data values for only one category in a stack on bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following barplot (code and image below). However, I do not values for each category. I want the label only for categories A and B on each bar while it should be removed for C and D. Please help! TIA

*Edit: I believe I wasn't clear. I want all A, B, C and D to appear in the bars. I just don't want values/numeric labels for C and D.*

```
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot all the data for all categories, but only show labels for categories "A" and "B" you can use the `dplyr` package to `mutate` a new column for which labels will be pulled from. A simple `ifelse` statement will replace any previous `Frequency` values with `NA`s for categories "C" and "D" and therefore will not be plotted as labels on the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

Data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(freq_lab = ifelse(Category %in% c("C","D"), NA, Frequency)) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = freq_lab)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want all A, B, C and D but the numeric labels/values (168 and 259 for A and B respectively in first bar) that appear on the stacks I want only for A and B.

Comment: So you'd like to plot all the values but only show labels for A and B across all year categories?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks :)

Comment: Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: Absolutely! Works like a charm. Thanks